# Https and Database in App - App Store Year-end self classification report

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

i want to submit my app to the app store and got the dialog for encryption. My app is using https to do REST requests to our own server (no other calls can be done within the app). The app is created with ionic/cordova and also contains a simple database for userlogin, and some other entities - created like this:

```
await createConnection({
        type: 'cordova',
        database: 'test.db',
        location: 'default',
        logging: false,
        synchronize: true,
        entities: [...]});
```

So im pretty sure that i have to create a Year-end self classification report. But im kinda stuck - the other columns i filled with the help of http://simonfairbairn.com/bis-year-end-self-classification-report/. i dont really know what i have to write for the last two columns:

> (11) With respect to your company's encryption products, do they
>   incorporate encryption components produced or furnished by non-U.S.
>   sources or vendors? Enter 'YES', 'NO', or if necessary, 'N/A' (250
>   characters or less).
>
> (12) With respect to your company's encryption products, are any of
>   them manufactured in non-U.S. locations?” If yes, list the non-U.S.
>   manufacturing locations by city and country. If necessary, enter
>   'NONE' or 'N/A' (250 characters or less).

(source: : https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/15/appendix-Supplement_No_8_to_part_742)

what do they mean? The app? the SSL standard itself? Or the issued SSL-Certificate the app will use - this i do not belive.. if the app would not be restricted to only our server like in my case - you would have to privide all SSL Certificates? -Never ever

The other thing is, do i have to create an other row for the app used database? Its a simple database where the default system encryption is used i think.